# How to investigate why Windows game is cutting off Wifi to everything?

Tags: windows-10, internet, malware-detection

One member of the household downloaded a game through Windows Apps. Whenever they play the game, all other devices connected to the Wifi router cannot use the Wifi. They show an active connection, but nothing loads.

We even upgraded to a new router with dual 2.4/5 GHz channels, and still this application stops Internet service to every device (iPad, Linux laptop, etc.). No other application has this affect on the Internet connection. For instance, if one computer is downloading a DVD-sized ISO, the rest of the house has slightly slower Internet, but Web pages at least load after some patience.

I went into Windows Defender and set it to block Internet to that game. The game still works, and the Internet problem is solved.

I'm assuming the application was doing something such as Bitcoin mining. What steps can I take to investigate what this software is doing?

Comment: Your hypothesis about some shady background process is plausible but there are many other possibilities. Some games tend to take as much bandwidth as possible to avoid lab but if the game in question works when blocked that wouldn't be the case. Have you already googled about the issue? Maybe somebody else is already trying to figure out.

Comment: Yes, I searched and nothing came up. I could find no mention of this problem among the negative reviews for the game on Amazon. I found news reports of other similar games (find hidden items) being Bitcoin miners, but no mention of this game nor company.